# How do I print something only when a given parameter does not equal an empty string

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to print out different options which are parameters to my function, however, i want my code not to print anything if that specific parameter is an empty string.
The code I have till now:

```
def ask_question(question, option1, option2, option3, option4):
#print the question onto the screen as well as numbered options
print(question)
print("1 ", option1)
print("2 ", option2)
print("3 ", option3)
print("4 ", option4)

#store answer under user_response
user_response = input("Your answer: ")


return user_response
```

This prints

How are you

1. good
2. bad
3. 
4. 

when parameters are:
("How are you", "good", "bad","","")

but I would like it to print:

How are you

1. good
2. bad

without including any options with an empty string

Any help on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off passing in a *list* of possible responses, along the lines of:

```py
def ask_question(question, options):
    print(question)

    number = 0
    for option in options:
        number += 1
        print(f"   {number:2}. {option}")

    while True:
        try:
            answer = int(input("Your answer: "))
            if 1 <= answer <= number:
                return answer
            print(f"Input out of range, try again.")
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"Input error, try again: {exc}.")

response = ask_question("How are you?", ["Good", "Bad"])
```

That way, you can cater for any number of possibilities, including checking input for validity as shown.

Comment: Although that makes sense and should work, this is for school work and I cannot use lists as they still didn't teach them yet. I was thinking something with if-statements but not sure what conditions to put

Comment: It should be very simple but for some reason I cant figure it out

Comment: If you can't use lists then all you have to do is put an if statement before each print..

     ````if option1:
         print("1. ", option1) ````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separate option params it may be better to just have one options param that takes a list. Then you can do this:

```
def ask_question(question, options:list):
    #print the question onto the screen as well as numbered options
    print(question)
    for e, option in enumerate(options,1):
        print(f'{e}) {option}')

    #store answer under user_response
    user_response = input("Your answer: ")


    return user_response
```

Answer (score -1):

I just used an if statement before everyone and it worked out fine:
ex:
if(option1 != "")
print("1", option1)
this worked and passed the test

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).